# Disable Azure Active Directory Single Logout

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, microsoft-identity-platform

Here is a scenario, I have given Single Page Web Application(just HTML and CSS) to authenticate and authorize the users to access this application.
So I used .NET CORE and Azure AD to authenticate users through Visual Studio (Register the app to the Azure portal). The login works fine but when I tried to logout it logs me out from all other applications that are using the Azure AD login mechanism.

For Example: In my browser, if I open Outlook that uses Azure AD authentication and my.NET application, if I want to log out from my custom .NET application, it automatically logs me out from Outlook. Is there a way I can prevent this? I just want to log out from my .NET application, not from Outlook or other applications that are using Azure AD authentication.

For logout: I am using the link: `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut`

Update: I haven't added the Azure AD as Connected Services on my .net app but once I added the azure ad on my .net app, the log out works perfectly for Google Chrome. (I can able to log out from the app without logging out from outlook) but when I tried the same thing with firefox(regular, developer) it logs me out of both application and outlook.
Looking at the network logs I found that after logout, firefox is calling `https://outlook.office365.com/owa/auth/logoff.aspx?cmd=logoff&exlive=1&lgtype=1&sid=xxxxxxxxxx` that logs me off from outlook but Chrome is not calling this URL.

Anything I can do to prevent this or should I have to contact Microsoft?

Comment: I tested in my side, and after my signing out from my custom web app in the Edge browser, then I refresh the outlook website in the same browser, it doesn't ask me to sign in again. And if I choose 'Stay sign in' when I sign in outlook, even I close the browser then reopen it, outlook also doesn't ask me to sign in. So could you pls share more details of your 'automatically logs me out from Outlook'? Btw, [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#sign-out) mentioned msal logout will clear the cache in browser storage.

Comment: When I sign out from my custom web app, it redirects me to Which account do you want to sign out of? page and when I click on my account it automatically logs me out of both outlook and the web app. Does your web app redirects to Microsoft pick an account to sign out page or it automatically logs you out?

Comment: Yes, when click sign out, it will redirect to the page to let me choose an account, and I choose the account which both used to sign in outlook and my custom app.

Comment: How are you implementing your Logout functionality? Do you use `/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut` to sign out. This is how my Logout looks like     <a class="nav-link" href="/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut" title="Logout">

Comment: For my springboot web app, you can see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNBBK.png), and for spa, you can see [this sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2), other samples for msal, click [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications)

Comment: Update: I figured out, I haven't added Azure AD as Connected Services in .net core. So I added Azure AD as Connected Services in .net core projects. It completely disables single logout from outlook and my custom-built application in Google Chrome. Still, the same problem exists when browsed with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to logout from the application only (which has a lot of security outcomes - eg. user clicks sign-in again and they will be signed in automatically), you can just sign out from the `Cookie` authentication scheme (which will result in the identity cookies being dropped), see: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L108 for the specific implementation by Microsoft in Microsoft.Identity.Web.

Simply create a sign-out endpoint in your controller and do something like:

```
return SignOut(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
    },
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
);
```

However, I **urge you** to reconsider doing this, Single-Sign-Out has really a lot of security benefits.

Comment: This clears out the cookies from the browser but doesn't log me out of my application. I can access the application without a login.

Comment: I think you might need to provide additional details then: Is it a Single Page App or MVC/Razor Pages or Blazor (server-side or client-side)? When you hit logout, it clears the cookies which is correct, because the user session (in case of Razor Pages and MVC) is stored in Cookies. What may be happening is that right after logout you end up at a page which requires authentication so you get signed-in again due to use of SSO...

Comment: Updated my question. Hope this makes sense