# How to log out from application but not from Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, logout

In my Asp.Net MVC application, I have recently integrated Azure AD authentication. The login is working fine, but I am not able to get the logout right. I would like to log the users out from my application only, and not "single sign out". Everything I have read is about single sign out. Here is what I have tried:

1. Abandon the session and redirect to login page. An error related to missing claims is thrown on the login page on Html.AntiForgeryToken() statement

   ```
   Session.Abandon();
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
   ```
2. This has the same error as #1

   ```
   FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
   FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
   ```
3. This takes user to single sign out

   ```
   HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   ```

Comment: Hello @Apeksha, any update on this .!? If the provided solution worked, could you please accept it as answer to help other community members for the similar issue.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT, you provided solution for single sign out, which is the opposite of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few  of workarounds as suggested by @Jan Hajek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872791/disable-azure-active-directory-single-logout)

- Make sure that Azure AD is listed as a Connected Service in your .NET  application.
  This will prevent a single logout.
- We can create single sign out endpoint in `controller` as below example

```
return SignOut(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
    },
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
);
```

**NOTE: -** When we hit the  logout, it clears the cookies which is correct, because the user session (in case of Razor Pages and MVC) is stored in Cookies .

Also we can set `redirect logout url` (e.g- "`<your-doman>/.auth/logout`") to the home page of the application itself where it ask for log in again .

For more information please refer the below links

- MS BLOG: [Expanding App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/)
- [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463426/azure-web-app-logout-from-aad-authentication?rq=1)
- MS DOC: [Customize sign-in and sign-out in Azure App Service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-customize-sign-in-out)